# Is dynamic code generation possible with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, dynamic, compilation

**Is there a way to dynamically create a class using Typescript which can be saved in it's own file to be reused later on in different projects?**

For example, let say I want to have a `SpecificationParser` class which can read some `JSON` specification file and create a representation of some entity.

I'd like then to dynamically create a class which will take the representation and reify it into a builder class, which will have dynamically created methods with properties (naming, type, params...) from the same representation.

```
spec: {
 a: {
     type: string,
     length: 10
 },
 b: {
     type: number,
     min: 3,
     max: 9
 }
}
          +
          |
          |
          |
 +--------v----------+     +-------------------+     +--------------------+
 |SpecificationParser|     |Representation     |     |DynamicClass        |
 +-------------------+     +-------------------+     +--------------------+
 |Parse              +----->Compile            +----->withA(value: string)|
 |                   |     |                   |     |                    |
 |                   |     |                   |     |withB(value: number)|
 +-------------------+     +-------------------+     +--------------------+
```

**The things I'd like to achieve:**

- Having dynamically created TS classes from specification file
- Those classes benefit from TS features (type checking ...)

---

Are there tools from TS environment that enable this?

If not, what tools could/should be used?

Comment: You can generate the code and compile it using the compiler (after all it's just a js module) but I think you'd de better off generating the JS. Loading the compiler is not cheap ..

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I get that JS trans-compilation is quite easy to achieve. But I'd like to keep type checking.